# Workmanager with multiple-processes

Tags: android, ipc, android-workmanager

Is there a way to enqueue work in work manager from multiple processes? Right now I’m getting this message when I’m trying to do it from the "non-ui" process

`I/WM-GreedyScheduler: Ignoring schedule request in non-main process`.

Work manager version I'm using is 2.4.0. I know there is 2.5.0-alpha2 right now, but I cannot use that in production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WorkManager 2.5.0-alpha02](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/work#2.5.0-alpha02) is the first version of WorkManager that has multi-process support.

There is no mechanism for using WorkManager across multiple processes in any previous version of WorkManager (hence why these new APIs were added in the first place) so you'll need to either upgrade to that version of WorkManager or wait for it to become beta/RC/stable.

Comment: So you're saying you cannot create a new instance of the WorkManager in the second process and start enqueuing work to it? (e.g. have one instance in process1 and one instance in process2 that can function independent of each other)

Comment: There cannot be independent WorkManager instances per process, no. Only by using the new APIs in 2.5 can you enqueue work from multiple processes

Comment: 2.4.0 has a bug with calcing isMainProcess variable.

mIsMainProcess = TextUtils.equals(mContext.getPackageName(), getProcessName());

If you specify process name of your application in manifest you will get false always, because your process name will be like com.example.app:{processName}